# Vim plugin to organise Python import statements

Tags: gratis, python, vim

I am looking for a plugin for Vim, to organise Python import statements according to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - standard library imports
> - related third party imports
> - local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

Furthermore I would like it to alphabetically sort the imports, within each section.

- **Must**: Split standard library imports from all others
- **Would**: Split imports that have been installed (3rd party) from local imports
- **Would**:  Alphabetically sort imports within that section
- **Must**: work for Python 2.7
- **Would** work for all version of Python
- **Ideally** would be installable as a .vimball

If it has some kind of weird dependency, then it must work under Linux, but most Vim plugins work on anything Vim does.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there's a better plugin to work specifically with imports, but a good bet would be to use the **Python-mode** (https://github.com/klen/python-mode) plugin.

It does a lot of things related to coding in python (better syntax highlight, code checking, Pydoc integration, refactoring etc.).

It can also auto **add and organize imports** according to PEP8, using the python-rope library.

To answer your more specific points:

- It **does** split standard library imports from others;
- It **does not** split between 3rd party and local imports;
- It **does** sort imports alphabetically inside a section, and lists *import foo* before *from foo import bar* statements;
- Works for Python 2.6+ and 3.2+;
- I couldn't find a vimball for it, but you can install it:

  - From a zip (available at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3770)
  - From source
  - Using your favourite plugin manager (mine is Vundle (gmarik/Vundle.vim in github))
  - With APT, if using a Debian-based linux distro
  - (You can find installation links and more detailed instructions in the repo README)
- The only "weird dependency" needed to use the plugin is that your Vim installation must have been compiled with python support (which is usually true, AFAIK)

Comment: Welcome to SoftwareRec.SE. This is a fantastic first answer. Well done.